# iOS - Detecting Promo Code in-app purchases

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, in-app-purchase

I have an app that uses non-renewable in-app purchase products. Today I am thinking of releasing some 100 in-app Promo Codes for my initial users.

The in-app purchases work as expected in the app, but I'm unable to figure out what kind of check I need to do on app if the user has redeemed promo-code on App Store already.

ie., How do I check whether a user has redeemed a in-app purchase promo-code when they return to my app?

Edit: I also need the receipt to set an expiry date for the purchased product based on its purchase date. How do I get this receipt?

Comment: You can't tell; Promo code redemption is treated just like any other purchase.  Getting the receipt is covered in the in-app purchase programming guide

Comment: @Paulw11 That's what I gather from their docs, but it doesn't trigger any of my `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`'s methods once they come back to my app. Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ProvidingPromoCodes.html

Comment: Do you add the observer in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or somewhere similar, so that the observer is always in memory?

Comment: No, only my payment screen has the listener. I will try to move it to AppDelegate. Also, one can redeem promo-code even before installing the app. Not sure having a listener is the right approach for this. I am guessing I need to just try to check if a receipt is present or not. I am also not sure how to get the `SKPaymentTransaction` object. AFAIK receipt won't have all the transaction details which I require to enable my services on the app.

Comment: You should create your payment observer in the AppDelegate (or in an object instantiated and held by the app delegate), as shown in the In-App Purchase Programming guide.  It is possible for transactions to complete across execution of your app; I would suspect that in the case of a promo code redemption, the transaction will be presented to your observer when the app is next launched.

Answer (score -1):

basically, you have two ways to do so.

1. If using StoreKit1, in this doc, [Implementing Offer Codes in Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/implementing_offer_codes_in_your_app)
   , it says

> When customers redeem a valid offer code, your app receives a successful transaction on the payment queue, and you receive a server notification if you’ve enabled App Store Server Notifications. The receipt contains an offer_code_ref_name field that identifies the offer.
> basically you can retrieve `offer_code_ref_name` from the receipt structure.

2. If using StoreKit2, you can use OfferID and OfferType in [Transaction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/transaction/offertype)

> To identify offer code redemptions, including pending redemptions, use the OfferID and OfferType transaction properties in StoreKit, alongside the App Store Server API and App Store Server Notifications.  --- https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/#offer-codes

Comment: Question is about promo code not offer codes